# onclick function for adding the amounts by javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

As I am currently working with my project for addcart. I have written  the javascript query for radio button can any one check this either my query is wrong or right?

JavaScript:

```
function get_radio_value()
{
for (var i=0; i < document."make_payment_frm".rmr.length; i++)
   {
   if (document."make_payment_frm".rmr[i].checked)
      {
      var rad_val = document."make_payment_frm".rmr[i].value;
      }
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="rmr" id="rmr" type="radio" value="3"  onclick="get_radio_value()">
<input name="rmr" id="rmr" type="radio" value="5"  onclick="get_radio_value()">
<input name="rmr" id="rmr" type="radio" value="10"  onclick="get_radio_value()">
```

Can any one give me the correct code? If I click those buttons that amount should be added with addcart amount. For example: if  my addcart amount is 27£ then I choose 2nd radio button finaly it should be display like a 32£.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off, it should be `document.make_payment_frm`, not quotes in there (that's for bracket notation, e.g. `document["make_payment_frm"]`).  Also, IDs shouldn't be repeated, your inputs should just be:

```
<input name="rmr" type="radio" value="3"  onclick="get_radio_value()" />
<input name="rmr" type="radio" value="5"  onclick="get_radio_value()" />
<input name="rmr" type="radio" value="10"  onclick="get_radio_value()" />
```

Then matching script to get the value:

```
function get_radio_value() {
  var rad_val = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < document.make_payment_frm.rmr.length; i++) {
    if (document.make_payment_frm.rmr[i].checked) {
       rad_val = document.make_payment_frm.rmr[i].value;
       break;
    }
  }
  //use rad_val here to add to whatever
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JXQhn/).

---

But since you tagged this jQuery, why not take full advantage of it?  Remove those `onclick` handlers and add a `click` or `change` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name='rmr']").change(function() {
    var val = +$(this).val();
    //use val, it's a number ready to add to
  });
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JXQhn/1/).

Comment: @mplungjan - to convert it to a number, you can use `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)` if you're more comfortable with it :)

Comment: because you said __it's a number__

Comment: @mplungjan - it *is* a number, the `+` does the conversion to a number, so `val`, the variable is now a `Number`. Test it yourself: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JXQhn/2/

Comment: @nick craver you have done a good job. but still i have  aproblem

Comment: @nick craver i applied every code but there is no change even that url also has'nt change. if i click any one of the following button no change at all ok Mr.nick craver let me explain about my project am working with  http://SPSMobile/make-payment.php/ if you visit that you will see the three radio buttons with some value what i want is if i click any one of the radio button that amount should be add with add cart then displayed.if i choosed addcart is 24£ mean then i click royal mail special delivery button that amount 5.5£ should go with add cart and displayed like 29.5£. plz tel me somecode

Comment: @mercylouis - You've provided none of the markup for your cart, etc.  That link doesn't work, so I can't see it there either...

Comment: @Nick Craver www.spsmobile.co.uk just visit that link there is a repair unlock mobile then u need to click make payment process after clicks you will see that page. thanks

Comment: @mercylouis - It wouldn't be much different for your total update, look at this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JXQhn/3/

Comment: @nick craver thanks gentleman. i will try if any  doubt with it let you know. thanks for your presicious reply

Comment: @mercylouis - Sorry, I only answer questions on here, so the answer helps everyone :)

Comment: What I asked was actually if jQuery does the numeric conversion for you, e.g. is val() an integer or float if the content is numeric? If so, no need to convert

Comment: @mplungjan - oh, no it does *not* automatically convert, `.val()` returns a string in every case except a `<select multiple>`, it returns an *array* of strings then.

Comment: Right. Just asking because you wrote 
`var val = +$(this).val(); //use val, it's a number ready to add to`

Comment: @mplungjan - right, sorry it's an unclear comment, I commented because *I* made `val` a number with the `+` operator.